# Precision of using timestamp as X value when adding XY values to chart

Tags: c#, charts, timestamp

I have a buffer that is updated every time I receive new data. I also create a buffer containing the timeStamps (I use DateTime.Now for that) when the data is received. I plot this values in a chart: X=timeStamps, Y=dataReceived. However, the X values, that correspond to the timestamp, only change 16 times per second (see embedded plot) and I am missing a lot of samples. I am wondering if its related with the precision of the DateTime.Now, is it possible? What is the error, if not?

Sample rate is 256 samples/second * 16 channels. When there is new data in the buffer, I raise an event. An event is raised inside this function:

```
 while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            float[] data = deviceAcquisition.ReadData(numValuesAtOnce);    
                        }
```

The delegate calls OnDataRead. I think the values of the _bufferRawData are correct so the values of DateTime.Now should be correct too.

Plot corresponding to 1 second of data
 [image]

```
public void OnDataRead(object source, EEGEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.rawData.Length > 0) && (!_shouldStop))
            {
                lock (_bufferRawData)
                {
                    for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                    {
                        // Append data
                        _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);
                        _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now); ////ADD TIMESTAMP
                    }
                }
            }
        }    

private void AddData() 
     {
          // Copy data stored in lists to arrays
          float[] rawData;
          DateTime[] xValues;

          if (_bufferRawData.Count > 0)
          {
              lock (_bufferRawData)
              {
                 rawData = _bufferRawData.ToArray();
                 _bufferRawData.Clear();
                 xValues = _bufferXValues.ToArray();
                 _bufferXValues.Clear();
          }

          // Add new data points for the selected channel chart
          int channelIdx = 0; //boxChannelSelection.SelectedIndex;

          for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
          {
                  // Calculate the channel where the smaple corersponds
                  channelIdx = sampleIdx%(_numChannels + 1);
                  foreach (Series ptSeries in chChannels[channelIdx].Series)
                  // Add new datapoint to the corresponding chart (x, y, chartIndex, seriesIndex)
                   AddNewPoint(xValues[sampleIdx], rawData[sampleIdx], channelIdx, ptSeries);
                 } 
           }
     }

public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, float yValue, int chartIDx, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries)
    {

        //Add datapoint
        ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), yValue); ///PLOT VALUES (timeStamp.ToOADate() doesn't change across samples

        // Remove old datapoints if needed
        double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds((double)(8) * (-1)).ToOADate();
        while (ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
        {
            ptSeries.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        // Modify minimum and maximum for new samples
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddSeconds(10).ToOADate();
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = _yMax;
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -_yMax;

        chChannels[chartIDx].Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: The resolution of DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow is about 15ms.

Comment: Can you clarify at what frequency the data comes in, and also if multiple "data source" are writing to the same object ? I see you use "lock", so multiple threads can write data ? What happens if data comes in and the lock is effective ?

Comment: I use one thread to plot the data in the charts. The OnReadData is called from the main thread. I added the clarifications in the question. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: I found the problem: the timestamps that I am generating dont correspond of when the data is collected. Hence, several Y samples have a very similar timestamp. I should generate the timestamps exactly for every sample, or use the sample frequency, which I think it is a better approach.

Comment: 256 Hz is roughly 1 sample every 4 ms, much smaller than the nominal precision of `DateTime.Now`, never mind jitter that may be introduced by thread scheduling issues. I agree with your assessment that if you know for sure the samples are generated at a known, fixed frequency, you should just use that frequency to determine X-axis value for the graph. Since you feel you've answered the question, you should post and accept an answer so others don't waste time checking the question, and so that others with similar questions can more easily find this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamps that I was generating don't correspond of the timestamps when the data was collected. Hence, several Y samples have the same or similar timestamps.

One solution is to generate the exact timestamp for every sample. That should be done when the samples are acquired. However, since the frequency rate is 256Hz, that correspond to 1 sample every 4ms. The precision of DateTime.Now is around 15ms, which makes this approach not suitable for a frequency rate of 256Hz. However, that will be a good approach for lower frequency rates.

The correct approach is to determine the X-axis value for the graph when the data is plotted. Since the frequency is fixed at 256Hz, it is easy to know the X values of the Y samples.